# What is the first occurrence of the helicopter(s)-chasing-a-car trope?

Tags: first-appearance

The helicopter(s)-chasing-a-car (or chasing a motorbike or other ground vehicle) trope is by now fairly well established in both live-action and animated television series and movies. See, for example:

- [The Spy Who Loved Me (1977)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXRolBgI97o)
- [Streethawk: Vegas Run (1985)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Qofut0F8ag#t=1m43s)
- [California Crisis (1986)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMse-cVkft8#t=1m39s)
- [Gone in 60 Seconds (2000)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQZaDwegLek#t=0m23s)
- [Rat Race (2001)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db5ZQQ4liV4)

There is an obvious similarity to the crop-duster scene in [North by Northwest (1959)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_by_Northwest), but I suspect the helicopter(s)-chasing-a-car trope predates even that. The earliest example I have seen is in:

- [**Whirlybirds: The Big U (1957)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3c9pl3gohNk#t=22m50s)

Did that indeed mark the emergence of the trope, or did it feature in earlier films or TV series?

Comment: Someone has downvoted this question without leaving a comment to explain why. That isn't especially constructive. If you are thinking of downvoting, please at least explain why, so that I (and others) can learn what it is that you think is wrong with the question.

Comment: Doesn't Dr. Wong (Edmind Breese) use his autogyro to chase a car with Henry Quail (W.C. Fields) in it in 'International House' (1933)..?

Comment: @wcullen, I haven't seen /International House/, but your comment sounds like it might have the makings of an answer! Autogryos ≠ helicopters, but they are so visually close (autogyros, like helicopters, are often called "whirlybirds" due to their rotors), and capable of such similar low-speed flight patterns, that from a film/TV perspective a scene like the one you describe sounds as though it could well mark the emergence of the trope. Good catch!